# xpath with Multiple condition in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Wants to locate element with multiple condition on particular row,

I want to Click on div which contains **ng-click="condition001"** which has parent link contains **Auto-001**

So query become like : Select element xpath("//div[contains(@ng-click,'condition001')]") where Link("Auto-001")

```
<tr ng-repeat="(abc, xyz)" ng-show="data.length > 0">
                <td class="x001">
                    <div class="x002">
                        <a class="x003" href="#">Auto-001</a>                           
                    </div>              
                </td>

                <td class="x004">
                    <div class="x005">
                        <div class="x006">
                            <div class="x007" ng-click="condition001" tabindex="0">
                                <i class="x008"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
</tr>
```

Please suggest relevant xpath code which can work for above criteria,

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java / Python / C#_

Comment: Its Java language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the *WebElement* identified through *xpath* as `("//div[contains(@ng-click,'condition001')]")` where it has *partialLinkText* as `("Auto-001")` you can use the following line of *Java* code :

```
WebElement myElem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='x003' and contains(.,'Auto-001')]//following::td[1]//div[@class='x007' and @ng-click='condition001']")));
```